# Can I override the css of the default modal launched by setUnsavedChanges?

Tags: css, modal, button-overrides

So the modal that pops up when this code is called: `unsaved.setUnsavedChanges(true, { label: 'Component Name here'})`
Looks like this:
[image]

The issue is that I'd like to remove the save button, and edit the body of this modal. The actual button looks like this in the console:
`<button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button_brand saveBtn" data-aura-rendered-by="714:0"><!--render facet: 715:0-->Save<!--render facet: 718:0--></button>`

So I have tried simple css overriding such as:

[image]

And I've tried adding the !important modifier as well to no avail. Even tried this mess:

[image]

How can I get rid of that button and edit the body of text?